etoc and hyperref or bookmark package (newly) nuking \tableofcontents
I think that the etoc and hyperref (and bookmark) packages are no longer compatible (they used to work together for me but suddenly stopped - hyperref looks like it was most recently updated).
(And to make sure that this is actually a question...) Is anyone aware of a way around this and/or a fix for it?
Please see MWEs below (it is the \localtableofcontents that I need to use, but the normal \tableofcontents is also affected).
Without hyperref or bookmark:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etoc}
\begin{document}
    \tableofcontents
    \section{Blah}
    \localtableofcontents
    \subsection{Blah blah}
    \subsubsection{Blah blah blah}
    \subsection{Blah de blah}
    \subsubsection{Blah de blah de blah}
    \section{Foo}
    \subsection{Foo bar}
\end{document}


As soon as I add either package my \tableofcontents and \localtableofcontents both no longer display:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etoc}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}
    \tableofcontents
    \section{Blah}
    \localtableofcontents
    \subsection{Blah blah}
    \subsubsection{Blah blah blah}
    \subsection{Blah de blah}
    \subsubsection{Blah de blah de blah}
    \section{Foo}
    \subsection{Foo bar}
\end{document}

or
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etoc}
\usepackage{bookmark}
\begin{document}
    \tableofcontents
    \section{Blah}
    \localtableofcontents
    \subsection{Blah blah}
    \subsubsection{Blah blah blah}
    \subsection{Blah de blah}
    \subsubsection{Blah de blah de blah}
    \section{Foo}
    \subsection{Foo bar}
\end{document}


Edit
This is the log from TeXstudio (Messages was just saying 'Process exited normally')

(old toc file detected; run LaTeX again (cheers from `etoc').)
Doesn't matter how many times I re-compile, that message persists.
From MikTeX:

hypperref was packaged on 28/01/2024
bookmark was packaged on 19/12/2023
etoc was packaged on 4/11/2023

I did re-install MikTeX after this started happening and when I checked etoc and bookmark this morning it was telling me that they weren't installed (even though they had been doing their thing). Behaviour persists still after explicitly installing them.

Specific versions? How recent is recent? Your second example works fine for me.

I just updated TeX Live and the example still compiles.

show your log you get no error, and this output in an up to date texlive 2024

Thanks, was working on Friday, stopped working over the weekend. MikTeX for me, not TeX Live (and I'm using TeXstudio)... There is a message in the log, about to post that - sorry, had only been looking at the 'Messages' tab in TeXstudio as it wasn't giving me any errors there.

The log is the contents of the file toc.log.

Sorry, here it is (if I got the hang of this markdown stuff).

Please copy-paste the log into your question as text. If that is absolutely impossible, use a pastebin service. E.g. on Linux or Mac: curl -F 'file=@<path to log file>' 0x0.st and post the URL here. But first you should try to reduce your document and hence your log so it is short enough to include in your question.

I'm adverse to Dropbox links and will not usually follow them, but I wanted to procrastinate.
From your log:
) (C:\Users\brad.mcclintock\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\tex/latex/etoc\etoc.sty
Package: etoc 2023/07/01 v1.2b Completely customisable TOCs (JFB)

and
(C:\Users\brad.mcclintock\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/hyperref\hyperref.sty
Package: hyperref 2024-01-20 v7.01h Hypertext links for LaTeX

According to etoc's manual (page 106), these are incompatible and the result is empty .tocs:

1.2c [2023/10/28]
Compatibility hotfix with hyperref v7.01c; etoc had copied over a now unneeded internal hyperref test, and since v7.01c
the result was that etoc produced empty tables of contents. Thanks to
Denis Bitouzé for report.

I have version 1.2d of etoc, so yours is two releases behind. More significantly, it is markedly old in comparison with the version of hyperref you are using.
MikTeX lists 1.2d as the current version, so this is probably a problem resulting from partial updates on your end.
If you need a short-term workaround, download a copy of etoc and drop etoc.sty into your working directory. I assume you need really to update MikTeX, but I can't tell you how that works or how to fix it as I've never used it.
This is not the only package loaded where the dates seem not to correspond with the dates of other things you're using. I'm not sure how MikTeX works, but this suggests you need to do the equivalent of tlmgr update --all but, as I say, I can't tell you how to do that for MikTeX.

Thanks so much! It says it is all up to date, but obviously it is not. Will play with my MikTeX installation to see if I can sort it out, but at least the underlying problem now makes sense.

@brad I've seen people sometimes say you have to do it as admin and as user - does that make any sense? If not, the problem is almost certainly on my side as I'm well beyond territory I've done more than view from a distance ....

Thanks @cfr, yes that does make sense... I was just about to report back for completeness anyway. I did another full uninstall and re-install (and for anyone else who encounters a similar problem, I uninstalled from the option within the MikTeX console). All seems to be working properly after the latest re-installation, so it definitely looks like something was corrupt in my MikTeX installation. Thanks again for your help. I wonder if I do need to bite the bullet and go for a full Tex Live installation at some point.

@brad MikTeX seems a good option on Windows. It wouldn't be my choice, but neither would Windows ;). One advantage of TL is you can have multiple editions installed and switch between them. So, you could revert to a prior year's release if your ToCs suddenly disappeared.
